# Using SQL to combine detailed and aggregated results

Tags: sql-server

I am developing a report against a SQL Server database. Using the query  presented here...

```
SELECT
f.FacilityID as 'FID', 
COUNT (DISTINCT f.PhoneTypeID) as 'Ptypes', 
COUNT (DISTINCT f.PhoneID) as 'Pnumbers'
from dbo.FacilityPhones as f
inner join 
     dbo.Phones as ph
     f.PhoneID = ph.PhoneID
group by f.FacilityID 
having COUNT(DISTINCT f.PhoneTypeID)<>COUNT(DISTINCT f.PhoneId);
```

...I have identified 107 records where the number of phone numbers present for a Facility differs from the number of phone number types (e.g., there are two distinct phone numbers, both listed as primary).
[image: query results]

I would like to be able to produce a detailed report that would list phone numbers and phone types for each facility, but ONLY when the distinct counts differ.

[image: desired results]

Is there a way to do this with a single query? Or would I need to save the summaries to a temp table, then join back to that temp table to get the details?

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired output for the sample data. Not pictures of your data. [Why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Wrap your current results in a Common table expression and join back to your type table and phone table to get the needed numbers... or just join to those in your current query...  but then maybe I don't get the problem

Comment: @xQbert Thanks! This is just what I needed for a tip. I just googled Common Table Expression and got some useful tutorials. Didn't know what that was called until just now. I'll be playing with CTEs.

Comment: Also note with your current query the inner join is not needed at all as you don't reference any of those fields.everything comes out of facilityphones.  However I could see needing to join to it after you get your results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what fields exist in dbo.Phone; but assume the number comes from there... Likely need to join to the type table to get it's description as well...

This uses a common table expression to get your base list of items an then a correlated subquery to ensure only those facilities in your cte are displayed.

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT f.FacilityID as 'FID'
     , COUNT (DISTINCT f.PhoneTypeID) as 'Ptypes'
     , COUNT (DISTINCT f.PhoneID) as 'Pnumbers'
FROM dbo.FacilityPhones as f
GROUP BY f.FacilityID 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT f.PhoneTypeID)<>COUNT(DISTINCT f.PhoneId))

SELECT *
FROM dbo.FaclityPhones FP
INNER JOIN dbo.Phones as ph
        ON FP.PhoneID = ph.PhoneID
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM CTE 
              WHERE FID = FP.FacilityID)
```

The where clause here just says only show those FacilityID's and associated records if the FacilityID exists in your original query (CTE)  (107)  If we needed data from the CTE we'd join to it; but as it's simply restricting data placing it in the where clause and using an exists will likely be more efficient.